# Spyder freezes on running session in tesorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, spyder

I am trying to build a model that classifies images from belgium traffic datasets, but spyder freezes when i try to run the optimizer and train operation in sess.run[]. 
i have attached the code below.

```
graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():


    images_X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32,shape = [None,32,32,3])
    labels_X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.int32,shape = [None])

    #biasInit = tf.constant_initializer(0.1, dtype=tf.float32)
    # Initializer
    biasInit = tf.initializers.GlorotUniform()


    #conv layer 1 - num_filtewrs = 128, kernel size = [6,6]
    conv_1 = Conv2D(filters = 128,kernel_size = [6,6],bias_initializer = biasInit)(images_X)

    #batch normalization
    bn_1 = BatchNormalization(center = True,scale = True)(conv_1)

    #maxpoloing 
    pool_1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2))(bn_1)

    #conv layer 2 
    conv_2 = Conv2D(filters = 256,kernel_size = [6,6] , strides = (2,2),
                    bias_initializer=biasInit)(pool_1)

    #Batch normalization 2
    bn_2 = BatchNormalization(center = True,scale = True)(conv_2)

    pool_2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2))(bn_2)

    #faltten
    images_flat = Flatten()(pool_2)

    #dense layer - units = 512
    fc_1 = Dense(units = 512,activation = 'relu')(images_flat)

    bn_3 = BatchNormalization(center = True,scale = True)(fc_1)

    dropout = Dropout(0.25)(bn_3)

    #logits will be of the size [None,62]
    logits = Dense(units = 62,activation = 'relu')(dropout)

    #converting the lofits - [None,62] to labels - [None]
    predicted_labels = tf.argmax(logits, axis=1)


    loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits,
                                                                         labels = labels_X))



    update_ops = tf.compat.v1.get_collection(tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        # Create an optimizer, which acts as the training op.
        train = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.10).minimize(loss_op)


    init_op = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()    


print("images_flat: ", images_flat)
print("logits: ", logits)
print("loss: ", loss_op)
print("predicted_labels: ", predicted_labels)    

# Create a session to run the graph we created.
session = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=graph, config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
session.run(init_op)    


for i in range(10):
    _, loss_value = session.run([train, loss_op], feed_dict={images_X: images_array, labels_X: labels_array})
    print("Loss: ", loss_value)
```

when i run the program line by line, it runs well until the last for loop, when it reaches the last for loop the memory goes to 99% and the whole pc freezes.

Comment: you are actually not executing anything until the last loop.  everything up to that point is setting up the computation graph.  The last loop you are trying to load I assume very large data sets into memory all at once.  I suggest you try to batch your data to help alleviate this problem.

Comment: have you tried keras?  it's a wrapper around tensorflow and is a little more high level and easier to use.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, the dataset that i am using has some 4000 images, previously i had built models that had more much more images than that, what's wrong is that there is no error, my pc freezes when i run the last line, and i had to switch it off, and restart it.

Comment: i will try using keras, thanks for your advice :)

Comment: that is not a lot of data. I'd try keras and use batch processing -- a low range to start and then increase the number and see if that doesn't work. let me know how it works out for you. please upvote if this was helpful.

Comment: this was helpful, thank you for it, and sorry i am not able to  upvote, i don;t have much repo for that.

Comment: Ok no worries.  Good luck!